# How can I prevent `am` from starting my activity?

Tags: android

I have an Android app and it has 3 activities; A, G and B. When the app starts users see Activity A. If user wants to navigate to activity B, app starts activity G and asks for a password. If the password is true user is directed to Activity B, if not back to activity A. None of the activities are exported. Problem is on rooted devices a user can start activity B from command line using

`am start -n package.name/package.name.B`

command. How can I prevent this?

Comment: There's no security without physical security.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Either do the actual security check in activity B or make G send on some kind of token to B in the Intent.

The token can be any random data generated at runtime. Since G and B share the same process they can easily get access to it, but other processes cannot (not without manual debugging).

But note all of these only make it difficult for users to use your app without the password. The user does control the binary and memory, so can bypass any protection you put in.

Comment: This is the better of the 2 current answers. If someone must only run after doing something else, then combine them.

Answer (score 12):

You cannot prevent AM from running on a rooted phone. My approach to preventing Activity B from being run separately would be to write activity B to fail unless it's passed a code from activity A or G, depending on which activity starts it.